# Firebase realtime database rules (all can read but edit only owner)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

So far I've been using this rules configuration

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      ".read" : true,
      "$uid": {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

validation and other directories omitted.
/items/user1/item1 
/items/user2/item1

All can read items directory and all user items (no private items)

What do I need?

flat array of items

```
"items" : {
     "item1": {},
     "item2": {}
}
```

with userId as property

```
"item1" : {
    "uid": "userId"
}
```

Only user created item can edit/delete it,  but all can see it.

I was thinking about double items in different directory such as

```
"public_items": {
         "item1": {},
         "item2": {}
}


"items": {
   "userId": {
      "item1": {},
      "item2": {},
   }
}
```

But it seems like not a good idea.

> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write
>   operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location
>   or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every affected
>   child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail
>   completely.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade

if rules can't be applied for each item, how to build items directory with different owners ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can handle this only using the `/items/itemId/uid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
        ".read" : true,
        "$itemId": {
            ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid ) || (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Above rules is a possible solution. We are allowing anyone to read everything that is inside `items`. But only users who owns the item (`/itemId/uid`) can create/edit. Also we are forcing that the new or edited item has the user id.